# How do I loop over _char_ data SAS

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

```
%macro var_in_list(z);
proc contents data=&z. noprint out=cont(keep= name);
run;
proc sql noprint;                              
 select Name  into :VarList separated by ' '
 from cont;
quit;
proc sql noprint;
select count(*) into :count from cont; quit;
%put &count.;
%put &VarList.;
%let a=;

%let finish=%sysfunc(countw(&VarList));
  %do i = 1 %to &finish;
  %put var_&i= %scan(&varlist., &i, " ");
    %ordinal(var_&i);
  %end;

/*%do j=1 %to &finish;*/
/*  %ordinal(a_:);*/
/*%end;*/

%mend var_in_list;
```

```
&varlist.=WOE_ASSET_TYPE WOE_CURRENT_ASSETS WOE_CURRENT_LIABILITIES_1 WOE_DEPRECIATION_1 
            WOE_DebtAmount WOE_Delta_TL WOE_Delta_TS WOE_Delta_interest WOE_Delta_npbt WOE_Delta_taxes WOE_EBITDA_COVERAGE WOE_EFA 
            WOE_EPP WOE_IsCodebtor WOE_NACE WOE_OutstandingAmount WOE_PPLTL WOE_PPTA WOE_PRODUCT WOE_P_price WOE_TEENOR WOE_T_L1 
            WOE_max_LD_1 WOE_max_LD_2 WOE_max_LD_3 WOE_max_LD_4 WOE_max_LD_5 WOE_max_LD_6 WOE_max_LD_7 WOE_max_LD_8 WOE_max_LD_9 
            WOE_max_LD_10 WOE_max_LD_12 delnum percbad tot
```

I want:

%ordinal(WOE_ASSET_TYPE);
%ordinal(WOE_CURRENT_ASSETS); etc.

I'm just trying to automate a simple process due to lazyness.

Comment: No need to re-run the query to count how many names you found.  SQL will set that into the automatic macro variable SQLOBS.  Just use `%let finish=&sqlobs;` right after the select statement that makes the macro variable with the list of names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing a macro variable you never create.  You don't really need any macro varaiable.  You can just pass the results of the scan to the macro call.

```
%do i = 1 %to &finish;
  %ordinal(%scan(&varlist., &i, %str( ) ));
%end;
```

Note your call to %SCAN() is setting both space and double quote as the delimiter characters.  It will not have any impact unless some of the variable names actually include double quote characters.

Comment: I'd go ahead and make the fix to remove the quotes in your answer, as it's certainly more correct to use `%scan(&varlist., &i, %str( ))` and not obvious necessarily how to get that space in there.

Answer (score 2):

Tom answered how to get your macro to work, but I'll tell you how to not use a macro.

```
proc sql noprint;                              
 select Name  into :VarList separated by ' '
 from cont;
quit;
```

That's what, 90% of what you want?  Let's just modify that.

What you want is `%ordinal(` then the value for name then `)`, for each row, right?  We can `cats` that, no problem, right in the `select`!

```
proc sql noprint;                              
 select cats('%ordinal(',Name,')')  into :OrdCallList separated by ' '
 from cont;
quit;
```

Now you just call:

```
&ordcalllist.
```

Directly in a line of code all by itself - and it will call your macro for you.  I don't include the `;` here as it's probably not needed - macros don't generally require them - but if for some reason you *do* need it, just add it to the `cats` at the end - `cats('%ordinal(',name,');')`